# When and how are annotations initialized in Java?  Can I control this?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, bean-validation

I have specified a custom annotation for use in Java bean-validation.  I use the same annotation class for all of my fields and pass a string parameter with the name of the field, like this:

```
@CustomConstraint(value="name")
private String name;
@CustomConstraint(value="address1")
private String addressLine1;
```

My constraint validator maintains a HashMap that maps String keys (name of field) to an Interface for my validation classes.  I statically initialize this map by pairing particular field names with concrete subclasses of the interface that will be used to validate the field, like this:

```
private static final Map<String, CustomValidatorClass> fieldMapper; 

static {
    Map<String, CustomValidatorClass> map = new HashMap<String, CustomValidatorClass>();
    map.put("name", new NameValidator());
    map.put("address1", new Address1Validator());
    fieldMapper = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

My concern is that this initialization process could be quite expensive (I have dozens of fields), and that it may be initialized for every single field which I am validating. I am hoping that there is some way to specify that the annotation should be initialized once and reused, or that this is the default behavior.

EDIT: I am using JSF 2.0 along with bean-validation, so I am not directly reading or calling these annotations.  That is handled by the framework, which is why I could not determine exactly how it was operating.

Comment: maybe [this manual](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/jsr-303.html) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and it seems that the static initialization I am doing on my map is only being called the first time I attempt to validate a field.  This means that the Annotation is not being initialized repeatedly and is instead being reused for each field.  My worry about overhead in my large initialization is now addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You questions is not very clear, and your design seems strange to me:

1. Why do you copy of the name of the field in the annotations? When you inspect the annotations at run-time, you know which annotation is bound to which field. Your `value` seems redundant.

   > @CustomConstraint(value="name-of-field"))
   >
   > type-of-field name-of-field;
2. Why map fields to validator in a static map? You coud define this mapping using the annotations:

   > @CustomConstraint(validator=NameValidator.class)
   >
   > type-of-field name-of-field;

I believe this is how most annotation-based validation framework operates, e.g. [spring annotation-based validation](http://springinpractice.com/2008/07/17/annotation-based-validation-with-the-spring-bean-validation-framework/).

**EDIT**

I guess that to read the annotations, you must be doing something like this:

```
for(Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()){
 Class type = field.getType();
 String name = field.getName();
 Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
}
```

So, you know how a specific annotation belongs to a specific field.

Comment: I am passing the name of the field in because I am using the same annotation on every field.  If there is another way to get at the name of the field the annotation is applied to, that would be very useful to me.

Comment: I think I see now that my example was not clear nor complete.  I am using JSF 2.0, and so I never directly read the annotations.  The bean-validation framework handles that, along with JSF.  That is also the source of my confusion, as I could not determine exactly how the process was happening.  However, after some testing, I think I have determined that the validator is only initialized once, and so I don't have a problem.  Thanks for your input!